# Determined dynamically column to update in stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, dynamic

I want to determine dynamically at runtime which column to update in a stored procedure

I have a table `BshForecast` that has attributes like:

```
projectId, JobTypeId, Year, JanDone, FebDone, MarDone... (for all months)
```

And I have this stored procedure that isn't working

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_Update_Done_Last_Month2] 
    @Project_ID INT,
    @Job_Type_ID INT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @LAST_MONTH INT
    SET @LAST_MONTH = DATEPART(MM,DATEADD(MM, -1, GETDATE()))

    UPDATE BshForecast 
    Set (CASE @LAST_MONTH
             WHEN 1     THEN JanDone    
             WHEN 2     THEN FebDone     
             WHEN 3     THEN MarDone
             WHEN 4     THEN AprDone
             WHEN 5     THEN MayDone
             WHEN 6     THEN JunDone
             WHEN 7     THEN JulDone
             WHEN 8     THEN AugDone
             WHEN 9     THEN SepDone
             WHEN 10    THEN OctDone
             WHEN 11    THEN NovDone
             WHEN 12    THEN DecDone
             END) = 0
    WHERE
        (ProjectId = @Project_ID) 
        and (JobTypeId = @Job_Type_ID) 
        and (Year = DATEPART(YY, DATEADD(MM, -1, GETDATE())))
END
```

What you think seems to be the problem? And what is the right way to do this?

Comment: The problem is: SQL Server's `CASE` statement can provide **values** - but not parts (like column names) of your SQL statement..... you cannot *dynamically* select the column to update. And also: your own stored procedures should **NOT** use the `sp_` prefix - that's reserved by Microsoft for its own use.

Comment: PS: it's **forecast** (with an "e" in the middle there) - not *forcast* as you have it....

Answer (score 3):

Try replacing your `SET` clause with this one:

```
SET
    JanDone = case when @LAST_MONTH = 1 then 0 else JanDone end,
    FebDone = case when @LAST_MONTH = 2 then 0 else FebDone end,
    MarDone = case when @LAST_MONTH = 3 then 0 else MarDone end,
    AprDone = case when @LAST_MONTH = 4 then 0 else AprDone end,
    MayDone = case when @LAST_MONTH = 5 then 0 else MayDone end,
    JunDone = case when @LAST_MONTH = 6 then 0 else JunDone end,
    JulDone = case when @LAST_MONTH = 7 then 0 else JulDone end,
    AugDone = case when @LAST_MONTH = 8 then 0 else AugDone end,
    SepDone = case when @LAST_MONTH = 9 then 0 else SepDone end,
    OctDone = case when @LAST_MONTH = 10 then 0 else OctDone end,
    NovDone = case when @LAST_MONTH = 11 then 0 else NovDone end,
    DecDone = case when @LAST_MONTH = 12 then 0 else DecDone end
```

Comment: also, take a look at the documentation for CASE:
 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The SQL CASE statement only operates on field values, not table field names.

As an aside, I would highly recommend that you look to change your database schema if you have the option to get rid of the JanDone, FebDone etc fields and map to a reference table instead.

Answer (score 0):

You could expand your current query to make it accurate:

```
Set JanDone = (CASE WHEN @LAST_MONTH = 1 THEN 0 ELSE JanDone END),
    FebDone = (CASE WHEN @LAST_MONTH = 2 THEN 0 ELSE FebDone END),
    ...
```

You just need a `CASE` per field you need to update.

Answer (score 0):

You could use **dynamic SQL** to achieve this - basically building up the SQL statement "on the fly" and then executing it, within your stored procedure.

Something like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[proc_Update_Done_Last_Month2] 
    @Project_ID INT,
    @Job_Type_ID INT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @LAST_MONTH INT
    SET @LAST_MONTH = DATEPART(MM,DATEADD(MM, -1, GETDATE()))

    DECLARE @SqlStmt NVARCHAR(MAX)

    SET @SqlStmt = N'UPDATE BshForecast SET ' + 
        CASE @LAST_MONTH
             WHEN 1     THEN N'JanDone'
             WHEN 2     THEN N'FebDone'     
             WHEN 3     THEN N'MarDone'
             WHEN 4     THEN N'AprDone'
             WHEN 5     THEN N'MayDone'
             WHEN 6     THEN N'JunDone'
             WHEN 7     THEN N'JulDone'
             WHEN 8     THEN N'AugDone'
             WHEN 9     THEN N'SepDone'
             WHEN 10    THEN N'OctDone'
             WHEN 11    THEN N'NovDone'
             WHEN 12    THEN N'DecDone'
        END + N' = 0 WHERE ProjectId = @Project_ID AND JobTypeId = @Job_Type_ID AND Year = DATEPART(YY, DATEADD(MM, -1, GETDATE()))'

    PRINT @SqlStmt        

    EXEC sp_executesql @SqlStmt
END
```

Dynamic SQL has its problems and issues - be sure to **read and understand** the excellent article [The curse and blessings of dynamic SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html) before starting to use dynamic SQL in your project!